# Prestashop v.1.7 I can´t acces to the subcategories of the menu

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I can´t access to the subcategories, when I hoover the mouse over the main category it appears, but then it disappears.I think it can be a problem of position or z-index in a CSS theme.

I also have a module installed for the menu that is called categories.

This is the website : https://joyanostra.com/
Prestashop version : 1.7
Theme : Jewellery

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, you have to find in the css of the theme this declaration `.header-top .top-menu .sub-menu {` and remove the !Important after the `top: 54px !important;`

If you can't add this to your css file:

```
body .header-top .top-menu .sub-menu { top: 31px !important; }
```